# Nextjs - Disable scrolling to top using history buttons

Tags: javascript, scroll, next.js, history

You can disable default scrolling to top behavior thanks to the "scroll" attribute of the Link component. Does the api have a similar solution when navigating through the history buttons ?
Thanks.